# Force user change password after first login asp.net mvc with Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm have a mvc app that use with form authentication security client and all the manage user's is made in server side with wcf protocol.
and in the server site I'm saving the user tocken in the sessoin

```
string token = Srv.ValidateUser(out isNewUser, model.UserName, model.Password, model.IdentityNumber);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
 {
  Session["Token"] = token;
 }
```

with this token I Identifies in the services
and the user name in the form authentication

```
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

and now I dont know how to force user change password after first login or after password expired.
 My config is:

```
 <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="20" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms path="/" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

In your Login post action, you can check LastPasswordChangedDate like so:

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(model.Email);
if (currentUser != null)
{
    if (currentUser.LastPasswordChangedDate == currentUser.CreationDate)
    {
        // User has not changed password since created.
        return RedirectPermanent("Login/?userName=" + model.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: first I don't use with membership seconds I do redirect in login action but I want to prevent use exit from the changpassword page without submit change password

Comment: If you are not using Membership, you must be using something to figure out user credential is valid or not. In your user table, you can maintain a flag isFirstTimeLoggedIn or store a date as LastPasswordChangedDate. These are the ideas, you will need to find a solution based on your needs and current setup.