# Reset the default password i asp mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 website which is using identity 2 for authentication.
I created default passwords for users, i want to force them to change theirs password in the 1 st login.
What is the best way to achieve that ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate:

see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689602/force-user-change-password-after-first-login-asp-net-mvc-with-forms-authenticati

Comment: Try the following suggestions in the following answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516818/how-to-reset-password-with-usermanager-of-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: @Ronald  but I haven't the LastPasswordChangedDate